# Error while connecting DB2/IDAA using ADFV2

Tags: azure, db2, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect DB2/IDAA using ADFV2 - while executing simple query "select * from table" - I am getting below error:

Operation on target Copy data from IDAA failed: An error has occurred on the Source side. 'Type = Microsoft.HostIntegration.DrdaClient.DrdaException, Message = Exception or type' Microsoft.HostIntegration.Drda.Common.DrdaException 'was thrown. SQLSTATE = HY000 SQLCODE = -343, Source = Microsoft.HostIntegration.Drda.Requester, '

I checked a lot and tried various options but still it's an issue.

I tried query "select * from table with ur" - query to call with read-only but still get above result.

If I use query like select * from table; commit; - then activity succeeded but no record fetch.

Is anyone have solution ?

I have my linked service setup like this. additional connection properties value is : SET CURRENT QUERY ACCELERATION = ALL

[image]

Comment: Look up the meaning of SQLCODE -343 in the documentation for your Db2 version and fix your query accordingly.

Comment: @mustaccio - thanks for your reply - Yeah we tried this as well but no findings. HY000 -343 Message: An internal network library error has occurred. A network level conversational protocol error has occurred.

Reason: The conversation protocol error code string reply message indicates that the server received a protocol command that is out of sequence in the current context.

Action: Review a client network trace to determine if the server returned an optional severity code or other optional diagnostic information.

Comment: **in the documentation for your Db2 version**

Comment: @AnilPatel __Always__ state your Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) when asking for help with Db2. The answers often depend on the platform and the Db2-version. So always EDIT your question to add these details.